# How find this binomial-coefficients sum $\sum_{k_{1}+k_{2}+\cdots+k_{d}=n}\binom{n}{k_{1},k_{2},\cdots,k_{d}}^2$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

> Assmue that $d$ is give postive integer numbers,and 
>     $$(x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{d})^n=\sum_{k_{1}+\cdots+k_{d}=n} \binom{n}{k_{1},k_{2},\cdots,k_{d}}x^{k_{1}}_{1}x^{k_{2}}_{2}\cdots x^{k_{d}}_{d}$$
>   can see:
>   [Multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)
>
> Find the closed form
>   $$\sum_{k_{1}+k_{2}+\cdots+k_{d}=n}\binom{n}{k_{1},k_{2},\cdots,k_{d}}^2$$

for example

when $d=2$,then
$$(x_{1}+x_{2})^n=\sum_{k_{1}+k_{2}=n}\binom{n}{k_{1},k_{2}}x^{k_{1}}x^{k_{2}}$$
we know $$\binom{n}{k_{1},k_{2}}=\binom{n}{k}$$
so
$$\sum_{k_{1}+k_{2}=n}\binom{n}{k_{1},k_{2}}^2=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2=\binom{2n}{n}$$
this proof can see:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

But my problem I can't it,can you help?

Comment: Have a look at: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/128249/estimate-on-sum-of-squares-of-multinomial-coefficients

Comment: In the OEIS you can consult A245397 and A033935.

Comment: When d=3,  the sequence is A002893