# Sum of squares of multinomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

It is well known that the sum of squares of all binomial coefficients ${n\choose k}$ with a fixed $n$ is ${2n\choose n}$. That is, $\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^2 = {2n\choose n}$.

But do we know what the value of the sum of squares of multinomial coefficients is?
In particular, I am interested in $\sum_{a,b,c,d} {n\choose a,b,c,d}^2$,
where the sum is taken over all 4-tuples ${a,b,c,d}$ of nonnegative integer whose sum is $n$.

Thanks.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128249/estimate-on-sum-of-squares-of-multinomial-coefficients. It is unlikely there is any "nice" exact answer.

Comment: Already for squares of trinomial coefficients there is a lot of literature but no closed formula (see https://oeis.org/A002893).  For quadrinomials, see https://oeis.org/A002895 which also gives extensive links, and also the name "Domb numbers" [Named after the British-Israeli theoretical physicist Cyril Domb (1920-2012)"], but no closed form despite the appearance of $256 = 4^4$ as the $n=3$ sum.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, indeed, it is unlike the case $\sum_{a+b=n}\binom{n}{a,b}^2=\binom{2n}n$ which is annihilated by the (first order) operator $\mathcal{L}=(n + 1)N-2(2n+1)$.

If we denote
$$f(n):=\sum_{a+b+c+d=n}\binom{n}{a,b,c,d}^2$$
then the sequence satisfies the three-term recurrence
$$n^3f(n) = 2(2n-1)(5n^2-5n+2)f(n-1) - 64(n-1)^3f(n-2).$$
For $f(n)$ to have a closed form, the recursive relation should be of first order, which it is not. Further, the operator $\mathcal{L}$,
$$\mathcal{L}:=n^3N^2-2(2n-1)(5n^2-5n+2)N+64(n-1)^3$$
is irreducible. Here $Ng(n-2)=g(n-1)$ is the *forward shift* operation.

By the way, even the following sum does not achieve a closed form (apart from variations):
$$\sum_{a+b+c=n}\binom{n}{a,b,c}^2=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k^2\binom{2k}k=
\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n}m\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}k^3.$$